# CSS: Can you refer to a class within a class?

Tags: css

Let's say I have this class:

```css
.dark-theme {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Can I refer to it within my css file? Something like ...

```css
.some-class {
    dark-theme;
    padding: 5px;
}

a {
    dark-theme;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: No...you can't..

Comment: However if you use a css preprocessor like SASS, you can.

Comment: With SASS you can.

Comment: Either use a preprocessor such as SASS or CSS custom properties.

Comment: will this be only background?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Maybe yes, maybe no. I'm interested in your response to both cases :)

Comment: @MichaelLynch CSS preprocessor huh? Thanks! That looks interesting!

Comment: You can also apply several classes to one HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions to accomplish this.

Solution 1:
Use css variables. 
(Not really doing what you asked for but good to know if you're not using any preprocessors)

```
:root {
  --color-bg-dark:  black;
}

.some-class {
  background-color: var(--color-bg-dark);
}
```

Solution 2:
Use sass which is a css preprocessor and put your reusable rules in a mixin.

```
@mixin applyDarkTheme {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  // Some other rules
}

.some-class {
  @include applyDarkTheme;
}
```